# Determine latest supported SSL/TLS version of my openssl library?

Tags: curl, ssl, openssl

I'm working with openssl version 0.9.8x on a Mac, and when I try curling to an HTTPS server I get `CURL error #35: Unsupported SSL protocol version`.

The server accepting the connections is Apache and the vhost has these two relevant lines:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
```

I'm thinking that my curl version *only* supports SSLv2, perhaps since it's so old, and that's why Apache is refusing the connection. Is there a way to verify what the latest version of SSL/TLS is actually supported so I can stop guessing?

For the record, I have tried forcing my local curl command to use SSLv3, but it doesn't matter I still get the error, perhaps because SSLv3 is not available to use.

**Edit**: The server has version `1.0.1e-fips`. I'm thinking maybe there is an issue when connecting to a server using 0.9.8 to >1.0 or something, since some of my google searching led me to believe SSLv3 is indeed supported in 0.9.8. Unfortunately I cannot recompile PHP to use a newer openssl on this machine =/

Comment: Its a Curl bug. From [Curl:bug #1319 Bug: "Unsupported SSL protocol version" Error](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/tracker-2014-01/0003.html): "Thanks for your report. This is indeed a bug and we have already fixed in git by Barry Abrahamson since commit 4bb74005298bb0c51".

Comment: Hmm, so that would imply that it's an issue with the server's version of openssl, and not my clients?

Comment: " I'm thinking maybe there is an issue when connecting to a server using 0.9.8 to >1.0 ..." Some of the 0.9.8 clients would hang if they encountered a modern server that supported secure renegotiation. It was fixed at OpenSSL 0.9.8m. Perhaps Curl is using a broken OpenSSL on Mac OS X. If you got Curl from MacPorts, I would suggest upgrading to latest as the first step.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error, because almost everywhere SSLv2 and v3 have been discontinued.
Firefox and Chrome discontinued SSLv3 as well.

Very helpful SSL/TLS Apache 2.4 how-to can be found [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html).

For best security, you would set

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
```

The '-all' parameter is removing other SSL/TLS protocols (SSLv1, SSLv2, SSLv3 and TLS1).

The '+TLSv1.2' parameter is adding TLSv1.2.

For wider browser compatibility you can use

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
```

Your cipher suite

```
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
```

Should be updated too. You can use:

```
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GC$
```

You can tweak and change any of the lines above to best suit your needs.

After a successful implementation, you might want to [test your server](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest).